# Django 1.8.8 TypeError

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to use Django to setup email and a simple form, but it doesn't work. How can I fix the error?

python==3.5.1
Django==1.8.8

the following error is thrown:

```
TypeError at /contact
not all arguments converted during string formatting
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact
Django Version: 1.8.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
not all arguments converted during string formatting
Exception Location: views.py in contact, line 60
```

here is views.py:

```
def contact(request):
form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
    form_message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')
    form_full_name = form.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
    subject = 'お問い合わせ'
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    to_email = [from_email, 'me@email.com']
    contact_message = """
        %s: テスト
        """ % (
        form_full_name,
        form_message,
        form_email)   #<-------error in this line

    send_mail(subject,
              contact_message,
              from_email,
              [to_email],
              fail_silently=False)

context = {
    "form": form,
}
return render(request, "forms.html", context)
```

Comment: the number of "placeholders" `%s` have to match the number of parameters following the `%`. You pass three parameters, you have to have three `%s` in the string

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
contact_message = """
        %s: テスト
        """ % (
        form_full_name,
        form_message,
        form_email)
```

to

```
contact_message = """
    %s: テスト, %s, %s
    """ % (
    form_full_name,
    form_message,
    form_email)
```

Its a [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) issue. Number of `%s` within the string must match number of parameters.